Estimation of particle displacement in meters from consecutive images
I have two images (img1,img2) in which the particles have moved. I obtained their displacements from the ImageDisplacements command, but I don't know how to calculate the displacement in the x and y directions in meters. Can anyone help?
Scaled image:

The command used to estimate the displacement:
dis = ImageDisplacements[{img1, img2}]


I think ImageDisplacements is overkill here. Also note I don't really know if all these images have the same ImageDimensions to start with, but I assume they do:
img1 = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/MtDBxHpB.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/4ablOz6L.png"];
scaled = Import["https://i.sstatic.net/fLs3Ud6t.png"];
(*resize to same size, binarize and ColorNegate*)
{img1, img2, scaled} = 
 ColorNegate@Binarize@ImageResize[#, {1708, 1024}] & /@ {img1, img2, 
   scaled}


We now make the assumption that the nearest ball in img2 to each ball in img1 is the same ball, and get the pixel displacements:
imgList = {img1, img2};
centroids = Values@ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"] & /@ imgList;
(*assume the nearest ball in img2 to each ball in img1 is the same \
ball*)
displacementList = (# - First@Nearest[centroids[[-1]], #]) & /@ 
  centroids[[1]]

(* {{-214.865, -102.129}, {43.4427, 142.142}, {489.748, 66.8481}} *)

And now scale by our scale bar, which is the component with the largest "Eccentricity" (longest axis/shortest axis of best-fit ellipse):
scaleBar = SelectComponents[scaled, "Eccentricity", -1]


And now get the pixel length of the scale bar and divide its actual length (3 m) by the pixel length to get the length of a one pixel:
lengthInPixels = 
  ComponentMeasurements[scaleBar, "Length"] // Values // First;
actualLength = Quantity[3, "m"];
pixelLength = actualLength/lengthInPixels;

And multiply by our pixel displacement list:
displacementList*pixelLength

(* {{-1.57028m,-0.746382m},{0.317488m,1.03881m},{3.57919m,0.48854m}} *)



Thank you very much for the advice @ydd. Do you think it is possible to estimate the velocity from the displacement obtained in meters per second? –

velocity = displacement/time so if you know the time difference dt between img1 and img2 then velocity = displacementList/dt

Thank you. @ydd you have helped us a lot, also we have benefited from your help to do an article. We invite you to participate in this research as a valuable colleague. I am waiting for your response (erabdi78@gmail.com). Regards Erfan
